# Old oil forced air heat only system (R/W wire only) - Is adding a C possilbe to use Wi-Fi

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

[image]This system is from the 60's era - the furnace has a two T connectors for the R and W (thermostat) and two F connectors - one labeled "Thermostat Load 24VAC 0.2AMP, the other for the Burner Motor Ignition. I want to use a Honeywell Sensi wifi thermostat and have no problem running a new wire to the thermostat for "C", but where would I connect it at the furnace considering the limited connectors (T T F F)?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide photos and/or a wiring diagram?